# Checking md5(password) match value stored in mysql

Tags: php, md5

I can't figure why this isn't working.
At registration I have (in php)

```
$data['salt'] = randomStr(3);
$data['password'] = md5($data['salt'].md5($data['password']));
```

Then I have an IOS app passing a MD5 encrypted pw ($xpassword) to the web app.
So I thought if I use:

```
$q1_result = mysql_query("SELECT password, salt FROM `members` WHERE `username`='". $username. "'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($q1_result);
echo "this should match? = " .md5($xpassword.($row['salt']));
```

The echo'd value should match that stored in the database as password

...but it doesn't
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: MD5 (even salted) is not a secure password hashing algorithm. Please consider using something better. A good library to use would be [this one](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat), which is an implementation of the standard PHP password API that will be included with PHP 5.5 when it is released. (the linked library provides the same API for current versions of PHP, and is written by the PHP core developers. It is secure, standard, and easy to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't match because you have the order wrong:

```
md5($row['salt'] . $xpassword)
```

In the first code you have `salt` + `password`, in the second code you have `password` + `salt`.

As @Michael also points out, you are double hashing the password which will mean it won't match.

Answer (score 3):

You are double-hashing the password part:

```
// Don't pre-hash the password before hashing with the salt!
$data['password'] = md5($data['salt'].md5($data['password']));
//---------------------------------^^^^^^^^^
```

You should only be hashing the entire concatenation of salt and password.

```
// Hash only the entire combination of salt . password
$data['password'] = md5($data['salt'].$data['password']);
```

And as already mentioned, reverse the order of the concatenation in your test:

```
md5($row['salt'] . $xpassword);
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you need to concatonate the string:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'blah' AND password = MD5(CONCAT(salt, password))
```